# Magento 2.3.0: How to add TIMESTAMP_INIT as a default value in declarative schema?

Tags: magento2.3.0, datetime, database-schema

As I'm adding CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default value for `created_datetime`
 and `updated_datetime` columns in my database table named `faqs`, I'm getting both the columns updated while edit the FAQ in admin form.

I want to update timestamp only for updated_datetime column. So for that I'm trying to add `TIMESTAMP_INIT` as a default value for `created_datetime` column and `TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE` for `updated_datetime` column as described follows:

> app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="faqs" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="FAQ Table">
        ........
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_datetime" nullable="false" default="TIMESTAMP_INIT" comment="Created Datetime"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_datetime" nullable="false" default="TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE" comment="Updated Datetime"/>
        ........
    </table>
</schema>
```

While running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command in cmd, I'm getting following error:

```
Element 'column', attribute 'default': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'TIMESTAMP_INIT' is not an element of the set {'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', '0', 'NULL'}.
Line: 12
Element 'column', attribute 'default': 'TIMESTAMP_INIT' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'defaults'.
Line: 12
Element 'column', attribute 'default': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE' is not an element of the set {'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', '0', 'NULL'}.
Line: 13
Element 'column', attribute 'default': 'TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'defaults'.
Line: 13
```

Can anyone please help me to correct the syntax or guide me how to achieve this in db_schema.xml? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to need update `created_datetime` and `updated_datetime` with `on_update="false"` and `on_update="true"` in db_schema.xml

> app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\db_schema.xml

```
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_datetime" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on_update="false" comment="Created Datetime"/>
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_datetime" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on_update="true" comment="Updated Datetime"/>
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Can you share some info on what these attributes do?

Answer (score 0):

[You can follow my blog for better understanding.](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/adding-timestampinit-as-default-value.html)

Introduction:
When working with databases, it's often essential to track the timestamp of various operations such as record creation or modification. Magento 2, a popular e-commerce platform, introduced the Declarative Schema approach to simplify database setup and maintenance. In this article, we will explore how to add the TIMESTAMP_INIT value as a default value using the Declarative Schema in Magento 2.

xml
Copy code

```
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" comment="Created At"/>
```